# Clarification on residue theorem:

Tags: complex-analysis

I've found the following definition: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdMwC.png

But I've seen it used to evaluate $f(z)= \frac{sin(z))}{z(z-\pi )^{2}}$

Using $res(f(z),\pi) $ despite pi existing on the real line. Confusing me as it's a singularity on the real axis...

Could somebody clarify how this makes sense / what I'm missing?

Comment: There is a first-order pole at $z=\pi$.  The contour must deform around this singularity in order to define the contour integral.  However, we can evaluate the integral over the real line in the sense of a Cauchy Principal Value.  There, the deformed part of the contour can be taken as a semicircle, centered at $\pi$, with radius $\epsilon \to 0$.  The integration around the infinitesimal semicircle will contribute to the value of the integral.